# Java 9 and TLS OCSP stapling

Tags: tls1.2, handshake, java-9, ocsp

I have installed Java 9 because I want to use the OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) feature with the TLS handshake, aka OCSP stapling. As https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-pki-programmers-guide.htm#JSSEC-unique_4307382 states, Java 9 is the first edition to make use of OCSP stapling.

To test it, you can set or read certain new properties, such as "jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension".

However, I get "null" instead of "false" (or "true") when querying this property with

```
System.getProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension")
```

Just tried it out with the new jShell:

```
[jshell> System.getProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension")
```

`$2 ==> null`

This is not supposed to happen with Java 9. Any ideas why? It is a so-called Early Access build which I downloaded two days ago. The official release of Java 9 is September 21st 2017 (yesterday). Unfortunately, there is no released version out yet for Mac OSX. 
Could it really be that this feature is not yet implemented in the Early Access Build (which is supposed to be close to the final release)?

Hope anyone can help here.

Comment: Is this `jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension` a JVM attribute?

Comment: @nullpointer 
The Oracle page (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-pki-programmers-guide.htm#JSSEC-unique_4307382) says:
"Setting Up a Java Server to Use OCSP Stapling
Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) stapling is enabled on the server by setting the system property jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension to true. (It is set to false by default.)"

So it is a System property. Not sure if that is the same as a JVM attribute.

Comment: But System.getProperty() will return null if there is no property with the key you specify, and that has always been true. Why are you claiming that "This is not supposed to happen with Java 9"?

Comment: I am not sure why I might be misunderstood. Didn't the sentence I cited make it clear that this property does exist with Java 9? It has been introduced with Java 9. It is not a property of the operating system, it is one of the JVM. So I don't get why it should be null if the sentence states clearly that it is set to "false" by default.

Comment: I suspect you are misinterpreting the documentation's meaning of "default" in this specific context. It is referring to the default behavior of the code in the absence of property settings rather than default values of property settings. See my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jshell returns null for your call to **System.getProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension")** because that property does not exist. I get the same result under Java 9.

You seem to expect that property to automatically exist under Java 9 but that is not the case; you still need to explicitly create it, and assign it a value of "true". From [JEP 249](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/249), that implemented this feature in Java 9:

> **The implementation will choose reasonable defaults for OCSP specific parameters**, and will provide configuration of these defaults via the
>   following system properties...

That doesn't mean that all of the OCSP properties automatically exist in Java 9 with default settings; it means that in the absence of those OCSP System properties the code will "choose reasonable defaults". For example, if the server cannot read the property jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension **the implementation** will (reasonably) behave as though the property had been set with a value of "false".

See also this code example for OCSP from an [Oracle presentation on security](https://cdn.app.compendium.com/uploads/user/e7c690e8-6ff9-102a-ac6d-e4aebca50425/f4a5b21d-66fa-4885-92bf-c4e81c06d916/File/3c93ea22f64e8a22f67d65c46613c466/j1_2015_con6710.pdf):

> ```
> // Enable OCSP Stapling (off by default)
> System.setProperty(“jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension”, “true”);
> // Yes, that’s really it!
> ```

So I suggest that you just explicitly set your client and server properties for OCSP as necessary, and don't worry about them not already existing under Java 9.

TLDR version: Java 9 supports OCSP stapling for TLS, but assumes that it is not enabled in the absence of any explicit configuration from the user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To me, the documentation can be misinterpreted very easily, but now I understand the meaning better.

So I set the property in my TLS server with
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.enableStatusRequestExtension", "true");
and let my TLS client and TLS server do the handshake. 

I still do not see any trace of those status_request[_v2] extension in the logging (with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl set in the JVM arguments).

I would have expected to see some mentioning in the ClientHello or ServerHello messages, but nothing.

Comment: Only after setting
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation", "true");

the TLS handshake fails with 

"main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not determine revocation status"

But still no mentioning in ClientHello or ServerHello about the usage of status_request or status_request_v2 extension.

Still a bit weird to me.

Comment: @Marc Setting the enableStatusRequestExtens‌​ion property is necessary, but not sufficient. For client driven OCSP you also need to set the security property ocsp.enable to "true". See Chapter 8 of the Security Developer's Guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#JSSEC-GUID-5B5A093F-FE4E-4D57-B66C-93CD6F78B1D1

Comment: @Marc But your issues now are distinct from the original OP, so ask a new question if you still have problems.